# ASP.NET MVC format grid columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format, grid

I'm this next code for datetime format in EJ grid

```
col.Field("BBDate").HeaderText("BBDate").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy H:mm}").Add();
```

it worked correctly.

But what do me write for double format? (Math.round(x, 3))
(variant Format("N2") set in all rows of column value N2)